# Using variable value to retrieve object value from the React class' state issue

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a state that appears like so:

```js
this.state = {
  dag: {
       topField: '',
       leftField: '',
       centreField: '',
       rightField: '',
       bottomField: ''
   },

   currentNode: ''
}
```

The currentNode in my program gets updates with one of the five variable names which are in the dag object e.g currentNode = 'rightField'.

In my program, I am trying to access the part of the dag which has the value stored in currentNode:

For instance, imagine currentNode = 'rightField' and that I am trying to log the rightField part of the dag object. Since I have found on other answers on StackOverflow, that to access the value of a variable it is common practice to write 'this[variable]' I have been trying this :

```
console.log(this.state.dag.this[currentNode]);
```

But I get errors for this which state that there is no 'rightField' of undefined. Yet I am still able to print the value using the explicit variable name i.e `console.log(this.state.dag.rightField);`
instead of `console.log(this.state.dag.this[currentNode]);`

[image: Erros]

Why is this and how do I actually use the variable holding the variable name (currentNode holding the position of right, left, top, etc) to get the correct part of the dag (right, left, top, etc)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`this.state.dag.this[currentNode]` <- Wrong.

dag doesn't have 'this' as a property. You are considering `this` operator wrongly. You should learn more about it.

`this.state.dag[currentNode]` <- Right

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_accessors

As Robin mentioned in comment, make sure `currentNode` variable exists and it refers to `this.state.currentNode`

Comment: Aw that was stupid of me, I thought I had already tried this and it didn't work but apparently it was just my brain that wasn't working! Many thanks :)

Comment: Shouldn't it be `this.state.dag[this.state.currentNode]`?

Comment: Both seem to work exactly the same... Any idea why they both work?